# Hover is not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Hover is not working in IE8, it swipes off the text when hover.

Here is the code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="divCls">
    <span class="textColor">Contacts</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divCls:hover{
    background-color:#E8F7F9 !important;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your code or put it in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5):

In IE8, if you are operating in quirks mode, `:hover` is only supported on `<a>` elements (which a `<div>` is not).

Make sure you have a Doctype that triggers standards mode.

See [the Wikipedia article on Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) for further reading.

Answer (score -1):

Try to implement link specificity using LVHA. See:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html

example:

```
   A:link {color: blue;}    
   A:visited {color: purple;}   
   A:hover {color: magenta;}    
   A:active {color: red;}
```

Comment: Who said anything about links?